# Multi-level image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code I'm working with:

```
$('#slider_1').click( function change_slider(){
  $('#slider_1').addClass('current_tab').siblings('.current_tab').removeClass('current_tab')
  $('#cart_slider_1').show().siblings().hide();
  $('#cart_slider_1').addClass('current').siblings('.current').removeClass('current');
  numItems = $('.current .cart_slide').length;
  sliderwidth = numItems * swidth;
  $('.cart_slides').css({'left': 0, 'width': sliderwidth});
  numloop = numItems-1;
  last_slide = sliderwidth - swidth;
  i=0;
});


$('#slider_2').click( function change_slider(){
  $('#slider_2').addClass('current_tab').siblings('.current_tab').removeClass('current_tab')
  $('#cart_slider_2').show().siblings().hide();
  $('#cart_slider_2').addClass('current').siblings('.current').removeClass('current');
  numItems = $('.current .cart_slide').length;
  sliderwidth = numItems * swidth;
  $('.cart_slides').css({'left': 0, 'width': sliderwidth});
  numloop = numItems-1;
  last_slide = sliderwidth - swidth;
  i=0;
});
```

It repeats 6 more times, with incrementing `#slider` numbers and `#cart_slider` numbers.

I want to make this into one set, and run the variable sets through it. `#slider_1`, `#slider_2`, `#slider_3`, etc... and `#cart_slider_1`, `#cart_slider_2`, `#cart_slider_3`, etc...

The current code works fine; I just want to simplify / condense it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#slider_1').click( function change_slider(){
```

You don't have to name the function when you pass it to an event handler.

```
$('#slider_1').click( function() {
```

An anonymous function is sufficient.

```
$('#slider_1').addClass('current_tab').siblings('.current_tab').removeClass('current_tab')
```

This seems to be missing a `;` at the end.

But neither of those is what you asked:

```
var change_slider = function() {
  $(this).addClass('current_tab').siblings('.current_tab').removeClass('current_tab');
  $('#cart_'+$(this).attr('id')).show().siblings().hide();
  $('#cart_'+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('current').siblings('.current').removeClass('current');
  numItems = $('.current .cart_slide').length;
  sliderwidth = numItems * swidth;
  $('.cart_slides').css({'left': 0, 'width': sliderwidth});
  numloop = numItems-1;
  last_slide = sliderwidth - swidth;
  i=0;
};

$('#slider_1').click( change_slider );
$('#slider_2').click( change_slider );
$('#slider_3').click( change_slider );
$('#slider_4').click( change_slider );
$('#slider_5').click( change_slider );
$('#slider_6').click( change_slider );
```

The basic idea is that we assign an anonymous function to a variable and then pass that to the various `click` handlers.  In order to make this work, we make use of the fact that when the function is called, it knows what object called it:  `this`.

```
  $(this).addClass('current_tab').siblings('.current_tab').removeClass('current_tab');
  $('#cart_'+$(this).attr('id')).show().siblings().hide();
  $('#cart_'+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('current').siblings('.current').removeClass('current');
```

In the first line, we can access our `slider` object directly.  The `cart_slider` is a little more complicated, so we rely on the fact that it just adds a prefix to the `id` of the `slider` object.  We get the `id` by calling `$(this).attr('id')` and use string concatenation to form the `id` of the `cart_slider`.

Note:  I haven't tried to run this.  Apologies in advance if I missed the syntax somewhere.

Comment: Thank you! that took my script from 127 lines to 60, and it worked like a charm. I couldnt figure out how to incorporate the "this" and 2 variables, but concatenation did it. Good choice in variable names eh?

Comment: One advantage of using named functions as event handlers is more readable stack traces.